# Python, extracting dictionary values

Tags: python

I'm trying to extract some values from a dictionary object and assign it to a local variable.   See this:

```
FTP_INFO = {'DATA': {'host': 'ftp.host.com',
                     'user': 'user',
                     'pass': 'password',
                     'path': '/home/user'}}
```

Then I try this:

```
v_host = FTP_INFO['DATA']['host']
print("HOST: ", v_host)
```

And I get this:

`print("HOST: ", v_host)`

`NameError: name 'v_host' is not defined`

Yet, this works fine:

`print("HERE: " + FTP_INFO['DATA']['host'])`

Am I missing something?

Comment: Pretty sure you're missing a typo.  Can you paste the exact code that you're running?

Comment: That's basically the code.   The dictionary definition, and trying to extract the host value and print it.   Does this have anything to do with it being a dictionary type or anything?

Comment: I think the "basically" is the problem.  Is all of this happening in the same scope or are these in different functions (i.e. you're declaring `v_host` in one place and trying to use it someplace completely different)?  It's impossible to tell without seeing the exact code from start to finish.

Comment: No, it is all in the same function.   I attempt to assign a value to v_host, and right under it, I attempt to print it.

Comment: I posted an answer where I copied and pasted this code and it worked fine.  I'm pretty sure you have a typo in your function, because there's no reason for a variable to magically "undefine" itself as you're describing.  If you won't paste the actual code from your function, though, I can't spot the typo for you.

Comment: _Yet, this works fine_ I'm not sure how that is connected to the error. Please see [ask], [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0):

I pasted this exact code (which as best as I can tell from your question is what you're running):

```
FTP_INFO = {'DATA': {'host': 'ftp.host.com',
                     'user': 'user',
                     'pass': 'password',
                     'path': '/home/user'}}
v_host = FTP_INFO['DATA']['host']
print("HOST: ", v_host)
```

into a Python interpreter and got this output:

```
>>> FTP_INFO = {'DATA': {'host': 'ftp.host.com',
...                      'user': 'user',
...                      'pass': 'password',
...                      'path': '/home/user'}}
>>> v_host = FTP_INFO['DATA']['host']
>>> print("HOST: ", v_host)
HOST:  ftp.host.com
```

So this works fine.  When you can find the difference between the code you're *actually* running and the code that I pasted above, you'll hopefully have the answer to why it's not working.